# How to express set belonging the other way?

Tags: notation, terminology

$x\in E$ reads "$x$ belongs to $E$".

$X\subset E$ reads "$X$ is contained in $E$".

$E\supset X$ reads "$X$ contains $E$".

$E\ni x$ ????? How am I supposed to read that?

I'm guessing "$E$ owns $x$"?

Comment: Taking a polemic tone, I object to all of your readings.  $x\in E$ is "$x$ is an element of $E$"; $X\subseteq E$ is "$X$ is a subset of $E$"; and $E \supseteq X$ is "$E$ is a superset of $X$".  While I would rarely write either $E \supset X$ or $E\ni x$, I would probably read the latter as "$E$ contains $x$ as an element".

Comment: "$E$ owns $x$": the 13th Amendment prohibits that interpretation.